# Turn List<Either<A, B>> into Either<A, List<B>>

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods

I'm trying to integrate [Arrow-kt's](https://arrow-kt.io/learn/quickstart/) [`Either`](https://apidocs.arrow-kt.io/arrow-core/arrow.core/-either/index.html) into an application that needs to parse and validate filter input. This input is a comma separated list of criteria. `Either` sound like a good candidate for that job because it does both jobs at the same time.

### Big-Picture

I've got a parser that takes care of the first step:

```kotlin
interface Parse<out T> {
    operator fun invoke(value: String): Either<String, T>
}

object ParseList : Parse<List<String>> {
    override fun invoke(value: String): Either<String, List<String>> {
        val values =
            value
                .split(",")
                .map { it.trim() }
                .filter { it.isNotEmpty() }
        return if (values.any()) Either.Right(values)
        else Either.Left("Value is not a list.")
    }
}
```

and other parsers that take care of an individual value like a date:

```kotlin
class ParseDate : Parse<LocalDate> {
    @Suppress("MemberVisibilityCanBePrivate")
    var formatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)
    override fun invoke(value: String) =
        runCatching { formatter.parse(value) }
            .map { LocalDate.from(it) }
            .map { Either.Right(it) }
            .getOrElse { Either.Left("Value is not a date.") }
}
```

Combining these to components results in:

> ```
> List<Either<String, T>>
> ```

so it needs to be converted into this:

> ```
> Either<String, List<T>>
> ```

### API

In orther to convert a List of Eithers into an Either of Lists i wrote the `merge` extension that processes each item and stops at the first `Left`, but keeps running on `Right` and collecting their values into a new list that is then return as a new `Either`:

```kotlin
fun <A, B> List<Either<A, B>>.merge(): Either<A, List<B>> {
    val result = mutableListOf<B>()
    for (x in this) {
        when (x) {
            is Either.Right -> result.add(x.value)
            is Either.Left -> return Either.Left(x.value)
        }
    }
    return Either.Right(result)
}

class MergeTest : FunSpec({
    test("Can stop on left.") {
        val list = listOf(
            "foo".right(),
            "bar".left(),
        )
        list.merge() shouldBe "bar".left()
    }
    test("Can merge right.") {
        val list = listOf(
            "foo".right(),
            "bar".right(),
        )
        list.merge() shouldBe listOf("foo", "bar").right()
    }
})
```

---

Is it necessary to do this on your own or is there a more clever way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is not simple built-in way to do this.

That said, your approach can be simplified a little bit:

```kotlin
fun <A, B> List<Either<A, B>>.merge(): Either<A, List<B>> =
    Either.Right(map {
        when (it) {
            is Either.Right -> it.value
            is Either.Left -> return it
        }
    })
```

It can be even reduced to a single line:

```kotlin
fun <A, B> List<Either<A, B>>.merge(): Either<A, List<B>> =
    Either.Right(map { (it as? Either.Right)?.value ?: return it as Either.Left })
```

Although this one is significantly less readable.

Comment: The usage of the `return` inside the `map` with the implicit outer `return` is crazy! I love it. I didn't know this was possible.